# How to deploy node app that uses grunt to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, gruntjs

I'm using grunt and also grunt plugins like `grunt-contrib-copy`, `grunt-contrib-mincss` (that listed as npm dependencies for my application).

Also I don't commit `npm_modules` folder and `public` folder, where all generated files are. And I can't figure out how to build my app (I have `grunt build` command) after deploy and setup my server (it's already looking for `public` folder).

I saw some stuff like `grunt-heroku-deploy`, but it seems me a bad idea to commit before upload. Maybe there are some gentle decisions... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

npm has a support for a `postinstall` step (among many others) that might be just what you're looking for.

The node.js heroku buildpack runs this command when you push to heroku to resolve build dependencies:

```
$ npm install --production
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#build-behavior

If you take a look at the npm documentation, you can setup a series of scripts to run either before or after anyone runs `npm install` for your package. It's configured in the `scripts` property of `package.json`. The `scripts` property allows to run custom scripts (including `grunt`) when certain things happen in a package's lifecycle.

For example, to echo some text and run the `grunt` command whenever anyone (including Heroku) runs `npm install`, add this to your `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "echo postinstall time; ./node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt <your task name>"
  },
  ...
}
```

https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html

Important caveats:

- You might have to change the path to the grunt binary in the `postinstall` script, check the error output if the `grunt` command doesn't execute.
- `grunt` and `grunt-cli` must be listed as a `dependency` in your `package.json` so it gets installed by Heroku. Listing them under `devDependencies` is not sufficient since Heroku won't install those. Also, note that Heroku won't install it as a global package so to execute it on Heroku you're going to have to use a relative path (as it is configured above).

If this doesn't work (you'll probably need to fiddle with the relative paths a bit), then you might want to consider writing [your own custom buildpack for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api).

### Update

As of 0.4, the `grunt` package no longer contains the `grunt` binary, which is now part of the `grunt-cli` package. The answer has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: My thinking on this has evolved a bit. While you *can* run grunt while deploying a node.js package, it's generally not a best-practice. It'd be cleaner if you deployed post-optimized (what grunt generates) Javascript code to your production environment instead of doing it on-the-fly. The slug approach described below basically achieves this.

Comment: Technically correct, but a bad idea nontheless. Wintamute's answer is a much better idea, which gives you clearer separation of concerns, for instance on how dev builds differ from production builds.

Comment: Heroku now has a guide for using Grunt: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-with-grunt

Answer (score 24):

This looks like it will largely be solved when the Heroku Platorm API `slug` and `release` features make it into the mainline.  At that point, you can build your code locally (or on a ci server), package it up and send it to heroku via an API call and release it from there.

This is still in the beta period and was only announced on December 19, 2013.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-deploying-slugs

I was never super happy with how many people seemed ok with checking in your generated code into git or the NPM postinstall hook. :(

Plus from a philosophical stance, doing a build during a release is simply another potential failure point.

---

**Just for fun**: Since that's not finalized yet, **here's a bash script** I threw together you can use for the time being to build your code on a deployment branch, commit it, deploy it to heroku and then remove the deployment branch.  (I really am not a fan of bash deployment scripts, so I'm *really* looking forward to the platform API additions)

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e 

# Delete current deploy branch
git branch -D deploy
# Create new deploy branch based on master
git checkout -b deploy
# Grunt comands to build our site
grunt build:production
# the dist/ directory is in my .gitignore, so forcibly add it
git add -f dist/
git commit -m "Deploying to Heroku"
# Push it up to heroku, the -f ensures that heroku won't complain
git push heroku -f deploy:master
# Switch it back to master
git checkout master
```

Comment: Great script, first time call to git branch -D may actually return "error: branch 'deploy' not found." and quit the script.

Comment: Great point @Andy - I think a good improvement could be `git branch | grep deploy && git branch -D deploy` for the first line.

Answer (score 23):

Grunt (et al.) is a build tool, not (really) something you should be packaging up and running on production. A different approach would be to use Grunt to prepare your project locally (or better on a CI server) before only pushing the built files to Heroku. As already mentioned Heroku will do an `npm install` on your app after its pushed which should be enough on its own to finally prepare your app.

I have it set up so that the Grunt derived/built Heroku app lives in a totally separate Git repo to my main app source code repo. So that when I do a `grunt deploy` it optimises and copies the relevant files to the Heroku repo, tidies it up (`git add -A` etc.) and then `git push heroku master` (or whatever).

It seems like a cleaner separation of concerns if your live servers are only responsible for running a pre-built app package.

YMMV of course, and the accepted answer above is totally valid too ... especially on a well understood and stable live environment like Heroku.

Comment: Interesting idea! Allows keeping a clean separation between dependencies and devDependencies, although I'm not sure the drawbacks of needing a separate repo would be worth it. (Maybe an e.g. 'master-deploy' *branch* in the main repo though, or something!)

Comment: I'm not sure there are many drawbacks to needing a separate repo. It'll only ever be linked to the heroku remote and won't need much setting up. You could even keep it .gitignore'd inside your main project directory etc. I'd say that's a better notion than polluting your main repo with an odd extra branch with compiled/derived code in it etc.

Comment: +1 for this approach - run grunt task locally, build to a folder (e.g. `dist`) which is a separate git repo. Then use something like [grunt-build-control](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/grunt-build-control) to push the repo in `dist` to Heroku. This way, there are no dev files pushed to Heroku.

Answer (score 6):

[Heroku buildpack](https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt) works fine for me. Great stuff.

Answer (score 2):

To get this working with grunt 4.0 I followed the instructions here https://discussion.heroku.com/t/grunt-on-heroku/98/2 . The only change I had to make was to remove the path to grunt as using unix style slashes would make it fail in windows and vice versa. Luckily you don't even need to specify the path as NPM will look for grunt in the node_modules/.bin folder https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html#path.

1. make sure you have both grunt and grunt-cli installed locally in your package.json even if grunt tells you to install the cli globally: $: `npm i -S grunt grunt-cli`
2. add a postinstall step to your package.json that looks like this: `"postinstall": "grunt prod"`

Answer (score 0):

The npm postinstall step is probably your best option, since you can invoke grunt from there. But you should also check out a custom buildpack, such as [heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt](https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt).

Answer (score 0):

This post is Rails-specific but I don't see why you couldn't use it with any back-end framework and just swap the Ruby buildpack with whatever you're using.

The solution is basically to use multi buildpacks, and have the Node/Grunt buildpack run `grunt build` for you right on Heroku.

**Significantly, this solution does not have you check build artifacts into version control.** (Yay!!!)

http://www.angularonrails.com/deploy-angular-rails-single-page-application-heroku/