# How do I execute custom build script when deploying node.js application to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

How do I execute custom build script when deploying node.js application to Heroku?

For example, I want to minify JavaScript files.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13796081. The question is about using `grunt` with Heroku, but the answer is generalized. Though, [`grunt`](http://gruntjs.com/) can help [with the build step](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-uglify).

Comment: why don't you do that before deploying?

Comment: @JonathanOng: I could, but from my understanding of how Heroku deployment/Git works, I need to create a separate Git repo just for deployment so I can push the deployment repo to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the use of asset-rack, which will minify files when your server first starts up, as well as providing fingerprinted versions of the files that can be cached forever.

https://github.com/techpines/asset-rack

Comment: Thanks, but JavaScript minification is just one particular thing I need to perform. I need a more general solution that allows me to perform any custom build steps.

Comment: Grunt is the best tool for any number of build steps. But take a look at asset-rack. It support browserify and other useful steps, and you may not need grunt after all.