# Best practices for Heroku deploy if you have an actual build process?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have a build process involving templating and file copying, which produces what I would like to deploy to Heroku.

But Heroku requires to push your source from a git repository.

What I currently see as my only option is to have a separate git repository, that only holds my build history.
My project is a NodeJS server application.

Is there a better approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Although I don't know the specific answer to your question, there is something you missed -> You don't need to push from a `github` repo. You just need to use the [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)) system, which is independent of github. Are you sure you can't use this system with your custom build process?

Comment: This was a typo. It's fixed.

Comment: :) I hope you find the fix! I'm interested to see what people come back with!!

Comment: Is it not an options to run the build process on the server?

Comment: I don't know, is it? :) Could you, please, add an answer outlining how should I do this?

Comment: Well that would depend how your build-process is defined. If you're using (or want to use) grunt I could explain how (or well the answers I used is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784600/how-to-deploy-node-app-that-uses-grunt-to-heroku). I can't say if it applies to other build processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a grunt-init project template that simplifies the develop-build-deploy cycle of NodeJS server apps deployed on Heroku.

Here it is: https://github.com/nicroto/grunt-init-heroku

This will allow you to have a single repository for your server & client apps, AND do actual build work.

I am basically creating an ignored by git build dir, which I synch-up with your Heroku app. And of course scaffold the project with sample init, build and deploy scripts.

I hope this will be helpful to the community. :)