# How to deploy node that uses Gulp to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, gulp

I'm using gulp and also gulp plugins like gulp-minify-css, gulp-uglify etc (that listed as npm dependencies for my application).

Also I don't commit npm_modules folder and public folder, where all generated files are. And I can't figure out how to build my app (I have gulp build command) after deploy and setup my server (it's already looking for public folder).

It seems me a bad idea to commit before upload. Maybe there are some gentle decisions... Any thoughts?

Forked from: [How to deploy node app that uses grunt to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784600/how-to-deploy-node-app-that-uses-grunt-to-heroku)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by adding this into my "package.json" file:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app",
  "postinstall": "gulp default"
}
```

The `postinstall` script is run after the build pack. Check [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process) for more information. The only annoying thing is that all of your dependencies have to live under "dependencies" instead of having separate "devDependencies"

I didn't need to do anything else with buildpacks or configuration. This seems like the simplest way to do it.

I wrote about the process I used [here](https://medium.com/@adambretz/heroku-gulp-c96dc3a8044d)

Comment: note that the npm scripts run with `node_modules/.bin` on their PATH, so `node node_modules/.bin/gulp` can be just `gulp`

Comment: I had to use `prestart` hook, because environment variables set in `heroku:config` wouldn't be available in `postinstall`.

Comment: If anyone comes across this, my gulp build task wasn't creating the assets when I ran `heroku run gulp build` after the build was successful. I checked the logs and nothing, and even checked the Heroku repo to see if there was any assets but the command was running but nothing was being created. However once I added this to my `package.json` it decided to work. Very strange, wish I knew why!

Comment: @KarlTaylor that is because `heroku run` called One-off dynos, it brings up new container, runs your command and kills the container, it's completely separate environment, not connected to your web dynos

Comment: Since my gulpfile only needs to run once & exit, as part of the build process, I got it working without switching `devDependencies` to `dependencies` because I noticed that there was a ` -----> pruning devDependencies` step in the heroku build process!

Answer (score 15):

You can do it!

There were a few key measures that helped me along the way:

1. `heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production` - to set your environment to 'production'
2. `heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/krry/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-gulp-bower` - to enable a customised Heroku buildpack. I incorporated elements of a few to make [one that worked for me](https://github.com/krry/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-gulp-bower).
3. A `gulp` task entitled `heroku:production` that performs the build tasks that need to happen on the heroku server when NODE_ENV===production.  Here's mine:

   ```
   var gulp = require('gulp')
   var runSeq = require('run-sequence')

   gulp.task('heroku:production', function(){
     runSeq('clean', 'build', 'minify')
   })
   ```

   `clean`, `build`, and `minify` are, of course separate `gulp` tasks that do the magic gulpage
4. If your application lives in `/app.js`, either:

   (A) make a `Procfile` in the project root that contains only: `web: node app.js`, or

   (B) add a start script to your `package.json`:

   ```
   "name": "gulp-node-app-name",
   "version": "10.0.4",
   "scripts": {
     "start": "node app.js"
   },
   ```
5. And like @Zero21xxx says, put your gulp modules in your normal dependencies list in package.json, not in the devDependencies, which get overlooked by the buildpack, which runs `npm install --production`

Answer (score 11):

The **easiest way I found** was:

1. **Setup `gulp` on `package.json`** scripts area:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "build": "gulp",
     "start": "node app.js"
   }
   ```

   *Heroku will run build before starting the app.*
2. **Include gulp on `dependencies`** instead of `devDevependencies`, otherwise Heroku won't be able to find it.

There is more relevant info about it on Heroku Dev Center: [Best Practices for Node.js Development](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices)

Comment: Where is `build` documented?  Didn't see it on the [npm scripts doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

Comment: Look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#use-npm-scripts-to-run-custom-build-steps for details about `build`

Comment: "build" command didn't work in our case, so we have been using "postinstall"

Comment: Strange thing this is not documented.
I have tried "build" only for Heroku. Maybe it works only there.
If you are deploying somewhere else, I recommend you to use other stages such as "postinstall" like @Tx3 is using.

Comment: I also used `postinstall` not `build`

Comment: @GrahamPHeath both are fine. You can rely in `postinstall` because it seems `build` is more linked to Heroku.

Comment: You can setup heroku variable `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` and you can leave gulp in dev dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

#### How to deploy to Heroku (or Azure) with [git-push](https://github.com/koistya/git-push)

```js
// gulpfile.js

var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var push = require('git-push');
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

gulp.task('clean', del.bind(null, ['build/*', '!build/.git'], {dot: true}));

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function() {
  // TODO: Build website from source files into the `./build` folder
});

gulp.task('deploy', function(cb) {
  var remote = argv.production ?
    {name: 'production', url: 'https://github.com/<org>/site.com', branch: 'gh-pages'},
    {name: 'test', url: 'https://github.com/<org>/test.site.com', branch: 'gh-pages'};
  push('./build', remote, cb);
});
```

#### Then

```
$ gulp build --release
$ gulp deploy --production
```

#### See also

- https://github.com/koistya/git-push
- https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit (`tools/deploy.js`)

Comment: i am gettting an error , can you please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462053/gulp-error-on-heroku-remote-syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list

Answer (score 5):

There's a specific startup script that Heroku provides;

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon app.js",
  "heroku-postbuild": "gulp"
}
```

note that in your gulpfile.js (gulpfile.babel.js if you es6-ifed your gulp build process), you should have a task name default which will be automatically run after the dependencies are installed via Heroku.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#heroku-specific-build-steps

Answer (score 0):

Heroku finds that there is a gulpfile in your project and expects there to be a **heroku:production** ***task*** (in the gulpfile). So all you need to do is register a task that matches that name:

```
gulp.task("heroku:production", function(){
    console.log('hello'); // the task does not need to do anything.
});
```

This is enough for heroku to *not* reject your app.

Comment: Have you got a link to the doc source that talks about `heroku:production`?

Answer (score 0):

I had to take a slightly different to get this working because I'm using browsersync:

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp serve"
  }
```

**gulp.js**

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: './'
    },
    port: process.env.PORT || 5000
  });

  gulp.watch(['*.html', 'css/*.css', 'js/*.js', 'views/*.html', 'template/*.html', './*.html'], {cwd: 'app'}, reload);
});
```

Setting the port to be environment port is important to prevent error when deploying in Heroku.  I did not need to set a postinstall script.

Answer (score -4):

It's possible to piggyback any command you want over the top of npm install. Much like the linked question in your post, you can add an install directive in scripts within package.json that will run after all the node deps have been installed that does the build.

Your main issue will be sorting out the correct relative paths for everything.

`{
  ...
  scripts:{
    install: "YOUR GULP BUILD COMMAND"
  }
  ...
}`