# How to deploy node that uses Webpack to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack

I'm using webpack.

Also I don't commit npm_modules folder and public folder, where all generated files are. And I can't figure out how to build my app (I have webpack build command) after deploy and setup my server (it's already looking for public folder).

It seems me a bad idea to commit before upload. Maybe there are some gentle decisions... Any thoughts?

Forked from: [How to deploy node that uses Gulp to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504476/how-to-deploy-node-that-uses-gulp-to-heroku)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
"heroku-postbuild": "webpack -p --config ./webpack.prod.config.js --progress"
```

this is better because if you use postinstall, everytime you do `npm i` the build script get fired

Comment: I was looking for a way to avoid building the app with webpack every time I was installing the dependencies, this is the right way to do it as per the Heroku doc (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#heroku-specific-build-steps).

Comment: All the other answers on StackOverflow use `postinstall`. This is the best answer for all of them.

Answer (score 14):

Do it in a `postinstall` script as suggested by @orlando:

```
"postinstall": "webpack -p --config ./webpack.prod.config.js --progress"
```

In this approach make sure to `heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production` `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true`

**OR**

You can find this **custom buildpack** [heroku-buildpack-webpack](https://github.com/jerrysu/heroku-buildpack-webpack) usable.

These links might help you build understanding:

- [heroku hook-things-up](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#hook-things-up)
- [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)

Answer (score 4):

In 2019, the simplest way to do this is to use the `heroku/nodejs` buildpack (automatically selected if you have a `package.json` at the root of the repository) and add a `build` script to package json:

```
"build": "webpack --mode production --config ./webpack.prod.config.js"
```

Heroku will automatically run this script on deploy. Bonus points because this is the intuitive script to run to test the build locally or in CI.

This is described in Heroku's [Best Practices for Node.js Development](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#hook-things-up) document:

> npm’s lifecycle scripts make great hooks for automation. Heroku provides custom hooks that allow you to run custom commands before or after we install your dependencies. If you need to run something before building your app, you can use the `heroku-prebuild` script. Need to build assets with grunt, gulp, browserify, or webpack? Do it in a `build` script.