# How to deploy webpack app to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, webpack

I am using a boilerplate called [este](https://github.com/este/este) which has a single repo for React server, client and native. Basically, I can see in the Procfile it mentions `web: node src/server` which points to the directory the node server resides (back-end APIs). The front-end app of the code is running on web-pack. What's the workflow to deploy web-pack apps to Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

[How to deploy node that uses Webpack to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223070/how-to-deploy-node-that-uses-webpack-to-heroku)

More references and documentation:

https://github.com/jerrysu/heroku-buildpack-webpack
https://github.com/choonkending/react-webpack-node
http://ditrospecta.com/javascript/react/es6/webpack/heroku/2015/08/08/deploying-react-webpack-heroku.