# How to deploy node that uses Rollup to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, rollupjs

I'm using Rollup.

Also I don't commit npm_modules folder and public folder, where all generated files are. And I can't figure out how to build my app (I have webpack build command) after deploy and setup my server (it's already looking for public folder).

It seems me a bad idea to commit before upload. Maybe there are some gentle decisions... Any thoughts?

Forked from: [How to deploy node that uses Webpack to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223070/how-to-deploy-node-that-uses-webpack-to-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Heroku, but according to the answers on the question this is forked from, it should be as simple as this:

```js
"heroku-postbuild": "rollup -c"
```