# gulp error on Heroku remote: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: heroku, gulp

I am getting following error on Heroku for a node.js app having Angular JS as client .

```
remote:        /tmp/build_4fcbc04371bd817841584e1f5427bd57/myRESTApp/ngClient/no
de_modules/.bin/gulp:2
remote:        basedir=$(dirname "$(echo '$0' | sed -e 's,\,/,g')")
remote:        ^^^^^^^
remote:        SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

My package.json  postinstall value is as follows :

```
  "postinstall": " node ./myRESTApp/ngClient/node_modules/bower/bin/bower install && node ./myRESTApp/ngClient/node_modules/.bin/gulp",
       "start":"node ./myRESTApp/server/server.js"
```

My gulp file is as follows :

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo '$0' | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../gulp/bin/gulp.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/../gulp/bin/gulp.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```