# Running a Grunt build task on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, gruntjs

I am deploying a Node.js application on Heroku. My production deployment is based on a Grunt task that minifies js and css files, placing them in a /dist folder from which they are called.

How can I add this step on the Heroku deployment?

Comment: check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784600/how-to-deploy-node-app-that-uses-grunt-to-heroku

Answer (score 0):

Use a `postinstall` script, as outlined in Heroku's DevCenter docs for node:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-with-grunt

eg:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "grunt uglify",
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
```